# Put other function on FormRequest in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm building a Laravel 6 application, and I am concerned about "best practices." I have one controller named CustomerController. In my controller, I want to update the Customer model, so I will have a function like the following.

```php
public function update(UpdateCustomer $request, Customer $customer){
    //
}
```

UpdateCustomer is my form request and where I will do the validation. In my update() method, I have classic validation.

```php
public function rules()
{
    $validationArray = [];
    $validationArray['customer.name'] = 'string|required';
    $validationArray['customer.vat'] = 'string|required';
    $validationArray['customer.email'] = 'email|required';

    return $validationArray;
}
```

Now I have to do some particular validation other the classic.
Let's assume that I have more data in my model, and I don't want these values to be changed.

For example, I have the following: `address, cap, locality.` I have a second method on the UpdateCustomer request that I can validate.

```php
public function validateForDataCantChange()
{
    $data = $this->input("customer");
    $customer = $this->route("customerID");

    $validator = Validator::make([], []); // Empty data and rules fields
    $arrayDataThatCantChange = [
        'address' => $data['address'] ?? NULL,
        'cap' => $data['cap'] ?? NULL,
        'locality' => $data['locality'] ?? NULL
    ];

    foreach ($arrayDataThatCantChange as $key => $v) {
        if ($customer->{$key} !== $v) {
            $validator->errors()->add($key, __("messages.the field :field can't be changed", ['field' => $key]));
        }
    }

    if ($validator->errors()->any()) {
        throw new ValidationException($validator);
    }
}
```

And then in my controller, I've added the following.

```php
public function update(UpdateCustomer $request, Customer $customer){
    $request->validateForDataCantChange();
}
```

Is this a bad practice? Should I create a new FormRequest? How, in this case (two form requests), can I use two different requests for a single controller?

Comment: Can you not just disable the fields that shouldn't be changed in the form and not update them in your `update` method? Seems strange to me that you allow editing of the field in the form but then tell the user that he can't change it.

Comment: yes, it is only example, maybe in frontend will be disabled, but was for specify if I have a different and validation other classic value. :) for know if in form request should be rules() function or could be others and if put in a second validation is a bad practice.

Comment: And because, for example, I can do this validation only if in my settings is setted for make this validation

Comment: In your example I would add everything into the `UpdateCustomer` `rules` method so all validation for updating a customer is in one place and you dont have to call a second validation method after it already was validated. I then would replace your custom code with the  [in](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#rule-in) validation rule to check if the values have not changed. Not quite sure what you mean with _only if in my settings is setted for make this validation_ but you could check your settings and then add these validation rules to the `$validationArray` array or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the little effort required, I'd personally create a new form request.

If you wish to use the same form request you can do the following:

```
public function rules() 
{
   $rules = [
    'title' => 'required:unique:posts'
   ];

   // when editing i.e. /posts/2/edit
   if ($id = $this->segment(2)) {
     $rules['title'] .= ",$id";
   }

   return $rules;
}
```

However, I always use a separate class for each action.